# Adding a third-party SDK to app

Tags: ios

[This page](http://beta.ubertesters.com/projects/1147/sdk) says to drag the SDK to your project folder?

I have done that, the folder is named `UbertestersSDK` and is a sibling to my `.xcodeproj` file.

When I add the line `#import <UbertestersSDK/Ubertesters.h>` to `AppDelegate.m` I get

```
'UbertestersSDK/Ubertesters.h' file not found
```

Comment: Does `#import "Ubertesters.h"` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* Not tested with Swift.

You have to add `UbertestersSDK` to your project.

So go:

> Files->Add Files to "Project Name here"

Then select all the files that need to be import.

Now your error should go away if you imported `'UbertestersSDK/Ubertesters.h'`

If you did this and it still does not work check to ensure in your `Build Phases`, the files are appropriately assigned. I'm unsure what Ubertesters files are (as you need an account to get the SDK) but if it's a framework, frameworks should be in `"Link Binary With Libraries"` and I think if you have header files they would be in `"Compile Sources"`.

Comment: This has not worked for me and I have added the UbertestersSDK to it as well. and Verified that the framework in is in the linking. I am doing this in the Swift Header

Comment: It's probably completely different for swift. This answer is specifically for Objective-c @hdost

Answer (score 0):

How to add Ubertesters to a Swift-based project.

1. drag **UbertesterSDK** folder (that contains UbertestersSDK.framework) into your project
2. add `#import "UbertestersSDK/Ubertesters.h"` to your *-Bridging-Header.H file(s)
3. add your Ubertesters Organization token to your Info.plist as a string called `ubertesters_organization_token`
4. In AppDelegate.swift:

   `func application(application:UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
       Ubertesters.shared().initializeWithOptions(UbertestersActivationModeShake)`